# Retrieving data from firebase database: UserId is null

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve data from a firebase database. But it returns `UserId` is `null`. I am already loged in to the account. I'm not getting what is the issue, could you help me with that?

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
online_user_id = user.getUid();
getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please put details of the issue to the body of the question, not to the title; there's also no sense to adding a picture of the code when you already added it as text (which is the correct approach). I've edited your post accordingly. Best regards

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=878273195715554&set=gm.1987346521286487&type=3&theater&ifg=1 please watch code here. give me solution